# 500 Internal Server Error. malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: Cache-Control

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5.3

Kindly help me,

My Ubuntu Server spec (Using VirtualMin):
Apache v2.4.18
Php v7.0.13

My Windows Notebook Dev Server spec (Using XAMPP):
Apache v2.4.23 Windows
Php v7.0.13

I develop Website using Laravel 5.3.30.
If i only deploy fresh laravel file, it works on my Server.
But if i deploy my ready simple application, the server give me: error 500 Internal Server Error. With log: malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: Cache-Control.

I have added 4 package to my Laravel:
- HTML Minifier: https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-HTMLMin
- HashIDs: https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids
- Laravel Collective: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html
- DebugBar: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

In my notebook, no error like that.

I dont know what information details to give. If someone ask some setting, i will update my question/answer.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: May be permission issue with storage?

Comment: I have give permission 0777 to all file and folder, but still give the same error.

Comment: did you run `composer install` and `dump-autoload`?

Comment: I have tried to execute `composer install` and `dump-autoload` just now, but still give the same error.  
I think it wasnt caused by laravel, because in my notebook when development, not showing that error. Maybe Apache setting or PHP Setting.

Comment: Try changing your these two files with the one in the link. It is just a test and might help you.
`.htaccess` : https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess  

`index.php` : https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php

Comment: Could be your `.htaccess` or some encoding issue with index.php

Comment: Just tried to replace the `.htaccess` and `index.php` with the link provided by @PaladiN. But still no luck. I'm so confused, why if i deploy fresh laravel it working normally both on my notebook and my server. But if i insert my application, its give me error only on server.

Comment: @ZemmyIndrapatih As stated here: http://www.mariusc.name/fix-error-malformed-header-script-bad-header-php-54/56/web-development-and-design

You might have some misconfigured `php.ini` file.

Comment: Thank for the help @PaladiN. Just now i already check inside php.ini, no line showing `magic_quotes_cpg=On` or `register_globals = on`. And even if i added line `magic_quotes_cpg=Off` or `register_globals = Off`, the error still exist. Huft..  :(

Comment: Just now, i'm trying to copy and paste all php.ini configuration from my XAMPP folder to my server php.ini, it show error in web browser instead of 500 Internal Server Error. I'm sure this is the problem with php.ini. But dont know which line should be added or removed.

Comment: Have you fixed the path for the php.ini in your server that you copied? If that is your local VM why don't you consider removing the lamp stack and try reinstalling it? It might be good idea.